# Iterate through Multiple user rows and verify they have the same Class with SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Server      User_ID     Class
_____________________________
Server 1    User 1      2
Server 2    User 1      2
Server 3    User 1      2
Server 1    User 2      3
Server 2    User 2      3
Server 3    User 2      3
Server 1    User 3      2
Server 2    User 3      2
Server 3    User 3      3
```

All users have an entry in the database for each server they are active on. 
Some servers have a mismatched class column for the user (ideally this would be the same across all servers for each user)
Ive broken it down and this is what I think I need to do to get this to work. I need to write SQL Query that does the following:

1. Grab a list of unique User_IDs
2. Cycle through each User_ID and for each one:

   a.  Check it against this table for all rows that contain the User_ID

   b.  Check that group of the single User_ID and verify the class is the same on all rows.

   c.  If it is, I need to put that in a column called is_Mismatched with either a 0 for not mismatched or a 1 for is mismatched

I could do this by calling the database within powershell, but with 300,000+ rows it is slow and cumbersome. Is there a T-SQL statement I could make that that would do this more efficiently?

Comment: You certainly don't want to do any looping for this kind of thing. Talk about slow. Are you wanting to add a new column for mismatched? In your sample data that column would be a 1 for User3 but 0 for User1 and User2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really, really don't want to loop in a database.
SQL works in a set based approach - you should think about working on a set of rows rather then working on each row individually.
Read [this article about RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) for more information.

Now, Assuming I understand your requirements, you should probably do something like this:

```
SELECT [User_ID], CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Class) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As is_Mismatched
FROM Table
GROUP BY [User_ID]
```

If you want to update the table, you can use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with the query above to get the values, and use it to update:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [User_ID], CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Class) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As is_Mismatched
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY [User_ID]
)

UPDATE t
SET t.is_Mismatched = cte.is_Mismatched
FROM Table As t
JOIN cte ON t.[User_ID] = cte.[User_ID]
```

Comment: This is a spectacular solution. Thank you for the recommended reading. I really appreciate it. The RBAR article helped out a lot. I am having some trouble understanding the CASE WHEN clause. Is that saying if there is only 1 distinct class then set is_Mismatched to 0 and if not, then set it to one? Also, is the Group BY part of that CASE WHEN clause? I notice if I try to pull more columns in the SELECT statement, I get an error because those columns aren't used for the CASE WHEN statement. I am assuming this is by design?

Comment: Group by and caseare unrelated. You should probably read a good sql tutorial.